# Approximating manifolds with boundary by closed ones

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Fix numbers $n\in \mathbb{N},d>0,k\in\mathbb{R}$. Do there exist numbers $N\in\mathbb{N},K\in\mathbb{R}$ depending on $n,d,k$ only with the following property:

For any compact smooth Riemannian $n$-dimensional manifold $X^n$ of sectional cuvature at least $k$ and diameter at most $d$ with geodesically locally convex boundary there exists a sequence $\{M_i\}$ of closed (i.e. compact without boundary) smooth Riemannian manifolds of dimension at most $N$ and sectional curvature at least $K$, which converges to $X$ in the Gromov-Hausdorff metric.

Remark. The assumption that the boundary of $X$ is locally geodesically convex is a necessary condition for existence of such a sequence.